# What's a good tool to create Sankey diagrams?

Tags: data-visualization, software, sankey-diagram

How can I create [Sankey diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram)?

Comment: R has a `riverplot` package for sankey diagrams. Never used it, though, so I can't testify to its usability.

Answer (score 9):

Have you seen [this list](http://www.sankey-diagrams.com/sankey-diagram-software/)?  And there is also a [function in R available](http://biologicalposteriors.blogspot.com/2010/07/sankey-diagrams-in-r.html).  I personally would start with the path geom and size aesthetic in [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) and see where that got me.

I haven't tested any of these.  If you find a preferred option perhaps you could let us all know as they are rather cool graphics.

Comment: There is an example (in progress) using Tikz over at the Tex site as well, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40159/8217.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for client side (JavaScript library) you can try:

http://tamc.github.com/Sankey/

You can also see a related question on StackOverFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545254/179529

Comment: Thanks for the link. And FWIW, HTML5 Canvas drawing code should also work on the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409106/generating-html-canvas-image-data-server-side

Comment: You are right. JavaScript is started to be used on server side as well (Node.js, Phantom.js). Just Most people here are usually more fluent with R...

Answer (score 3):

Check out my HTML5 D3 Sankey Diagram Generator - complete with self-loops and all :) http://sankey.csaladen.es

Comment: This seems to be based on the D3 Sankey plugin: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for library or web app? If the second, you may try this Sankey Builder. It has visual interface and drag&drop UI. It is just Beta, at this point it only saves data to it's URL and is not optimised for mobile.

http://wikibudgets.org/sankey/

disclaimer: I work for wikiBudgets

Comment: Link only answers aren't sufficient. For example, please see the mentions of links in the help [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Links may also disappear without warning; your answer should be able to stand on its own even if the link disappears. Please edit to give the essential information, and give a proper reference

Comment: @Glen_b I'm not sure how this answer could be improved. The question is about a tool to create Sankey diagrams, and the tool is accessible via that link.

Comment: @Patrick the links I gave in my comment indicate precisely how to improve the answer (as does the second half of my comment -- the kind of thing that needs to be done is to explain what the link goes to (what, exactly, will be found there) in a way that would be sufficient for it to be found via a search engine even if the link were to move and give credit/reference to the source i.e. explain who did the thing being linked to)

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded a brand new online Sankey Builder. You can upload data, configure via a wide range of tools and save. It allows you to drag and drop fields from your data to customize the Sankey Flow and dynamically add filters on any field in the diagram to squeeze the data. It has automatic highlights of bands across the diagram to highlight data relationships, and you can even mix and match colors. It features automatic paging for large data sets! A sort feature operates by value or field in ascending order.

All settings can be saved for a future visit.  The tool includes a share feature which allows you to enable or disable any of the settings.  The unique URL created by the tool allows you to distribute the Sankey Diagram to visitors for a read-only interactive version of Sankey Builder!  Check out the demo (see below).  You can even build a free Sankey diagram which is hosted for free. Simply visit http://SankeyBuilder.com and signup (all you need is an email address).  That will get you access to SankeyBuilder for free. Demo: http://sankeybuilder.com/sankeybuilder.aspx?url=bbe34d97f8 and Tutorials are at http://sankeybuilder.com.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Our Sankey Diagram app is for Apple iOS.  It uses the touch interface to provide intuitive creation of flow diagrams. Just search for "Sankey Diagram" in the Apple iTunes app store.  Our web site is [squishLogic Sankey Diagram](http://www.squishlogic.com/Sankey/)

Answer (score 1):

Draw Sankey diagrams directly in your browser with "Sankey Flow Show - Attractive flow diagrams made in minutes!"
http://www.sankeyflowshow.com

[image: Interactive (!) sample from www.sankeyflowshow.com]

Answer (score 0):

Like everything Latex is the way !

It you do not know latex at all you might not want this solution, but if you know even just a little, you just to have to change parameters accordingly to what you want, and it will be more precise and flexible than many other possibilities.

Note that you will have to enter the values manually.

You can use the Tikz library to produce that[image]

[Here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sankey-diagram/) is the code

Answer (score -1):

We build on Denes's online (web app) Sankey Diagram Generator with some more functions and abilties to copy data in from CSV, Excel Pivot Tables, and JSON.
[Sankey Diagram Generator](http://sankey-diagram-generator.acquireprocure.com/)