# What is the name of this kind of visualization, with arrows showing count of different subsets?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, sankey-diagram

What is the name of this kind of visualization? It uses arrows to show the count of parts of the sample set of an experiment.

[image: visualization]

This is from

> "[Measuring Reproducibility in Computer Systems Research](http://reproducibility.cs.arizona.edu/v1/tr.pdf)." Christian Collberg, Todd Proebsting, Gina Moraila, Akash Shankaran, Zuoming Shi, Alex M Warren. March 21, 2014.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is called a [Sankey Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram). A notable example is Charles Joseph Minard's [visualization of Napoleon's invasion of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Joseph_Minard).

(Edit) Also of interest may be these questions:

- [What's a good tool to create Sankey diagrams?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24074/whats-a-good-tool-to-create-sankey-diagrams)
- [What is the proper name for a "river plot" visualisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87132/what-is-the-proper-name-for-a-river-plot-visualisation)