# What is this kind of chart is this (shows flow of components from one group to another)?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, interactive-visualization

I'd like to know the name for the following type of chart. I see it in the context of interactive charts related to fundraising or polling where components are shown to follow from one group to another.

What are the common tools to produce this type of chart. 39~

[image]

Comment: also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388535/what-type-of-chart-is-this-a-crossing-stacked-area-chart/

Comment: And as for tools for producing them see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24074/whats-a-good-tool-to-create-sankey-diagrams/ (among other hits)